# Shader white on Quest 2 when reflection intensity > 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering, oculus, oculusquest

I'm having problem with a shader that becomes white with a few black spots in it when uploading it to Quest 2 but works fine in Unity. I tried minimizing unknown factors by exporting it to a new URP project containing only this crystal, its shaders and textures as well as the XR Plugin required to build and run to quest 2. I tried changing different properties on the shader to see if any would affect the white issue. This shader has a reflection intensity value that makes it shiny in Unity but if it is anything above 0 it will just be white on Quest 2.

I would really like to understand why and if there is any way of getting this to work on Quest 2. I just don't have enough knowledge to know where to look or what to try to solve this. I tried googling but did not find anything helpful, perhaps I do not have enough knowledge to know the right questions to ask...

A minimal reproducable project can be found here if anyone would be interested in seeing more details https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dd-758kJmsAedePDtUakIBqsB9Z39LAx/view?usp=sharing.

If seeing the shader code helps you understand it, you can take a look at it here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R4-tq-g4GUYl-BvKsKM2LCb06o_oYCzZ/view?usp=sharing

Screenshot from Q2
https://imgshare.io/images/2021/07/17/white-crystal.jpg

Screenshot from Unity
https://imgshare.io/image/blue-crystal.pq5hyS